# Is a for-loop index counter stored in cache?

Tags: c, for-loop, caching, optimization, cpu

So I have been thinking and reading about CPU cache optimization (on a MIPS R4000-like CPU specifically) and am wondering whether the for-loop `i` variable is stored in cache and whether this has consequences for what data inside the for-loop will be cached.

Let's say I have an array containing the data I want to loop over. The data is tightly packed and should utilize the CPU cache nicely. Would there be a difference in these 2 ways of looping over this data?

1. For loop using `i` index counter
2. Terminating `null` as last item in the array

Assuming 32-bits; would this mean that in case 1 I would have 4 bytes less to utilize on the cache since this is taken up by the index counter? Or would the counter be put in a register or something?

I am relatively new and uneducated on this kind of optimization topic and I imagine that different optimization settings for the compiler would also impact this. I am curious to hear whether anyone has any info on this or can point me to a resource I could read to answer my question.

Thanks,

Comment: I wouldn't it expect to matter. If your array is not yet cached, such a loop is limited by memory-to-cpu bandwidth. If it is already cached, all depends on a smart choice of instructions by your compiler. Trust your compiler, they are good nowadays with these things.

Comment: Most likely, if the code will benefit from it, the counter will be in a register.  Otherwise, it will be in the cache if you’ll benefit from that.  Trust the compiler.  You’ve got more important things to worry about.

Comment: This might help you 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302354/memory-cache-performance-in-working-with-arrays-in-c

Comment: Thanks guys, maybe I am overthinking it a bit